# Absolutet Value Inequality with cases number line

Tags: algebra-precalculus, absolute-value

I was wondering if anyone knows how to solve $|ax+b|<cx+d$ type questions by using cases and the number line to finish. I am personally struggling with the number line, I have half-finished a sample question by I am unsure of how to use the number to finish it.

$|2x-4|<6x$

Case 1: $x\le 2$

$-2x+4<6x$

$x>{1\over2}$

Case 2:x>2

$2x-4\lt6x$

$x>-1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have followed the right path.

**Case 1:** here, you have strictly restricted $x$ to less-than-or-equal-to $2$.  The solution you got  was $x > 1/2$.  Keeping the initial restriction in mind, you have $1/2<x \le 2$.   Remember that you have ignored the numbers that follow $2$ because they don't follow the original restriction $x \le 2$.

**Case 2:**  here, you have strictly restricted $x$ to greater than $2$.  The solution you got was $x > -1$.  Keeping the initial restrictions in mind, you get $x > 2$ as you will ignore all the numbers between $-1$ and $2$ (since they don't follow your original restriction).

So, finally, you get the solution $2 \ge x> 1/2$ and $x >2$.  Here is where the number line comes into play.  Represent your solutions on a number line, and you'll notice that it's the same as $x > 1/2$.

[image]

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply, but do you have any idea how i would use a number to work this out?

Comment: A number?  I'm not sure if I perfectly understand your query.  Do you mean a number line?

Comment: yea number line sorry for the typo

Comment: A number line wouldn't be much of a solution.  It can only be used to represent numbers.  Depending on different contexts, it's used in different ways.  Here, the question might be asking you to use a number line for representing the solution of this inequality.

Comment: So why is it that when I enter the question in Wolfram Alpha I get x>1/2

Comment: Done!  Also included the number line.